# Why during HashMap iteration, changing value of a key/value pair doesn't throw ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, hashmap, iterator

For example see the following code snippet:

```
        Map<String,String> unsafemap=new HashMap<>();
        unsafemap.put("hello",null);
        unsafemap.put(null, null);
        unsafemap.put("world","hello");
        unsafemap.put("foo","hello");
        unsafemap.put("bar","hello");
        unsafemap.put("john","hello");
        unsafemap.put("doe","hello");

        System.out.println("changing null values");

                for(Iterator<Map.Entry<String,String>> i=unsafemap.entrySet().iterator();i.hasNext();){

                    Map.Entry<String,String> e=i.next();

                    System.out.println("key : "+e.getKey()+" value :"+e.getValue());
                    if(e.getValue() == null){

                        //why is the below line not throwing ConcurrentModificationException
                        unsafemap.put(e.getKey(), "no data");

                        //same result, no ConcurrentModificationException thrown
                        e.setValue("no data");
                        }

                    //throws ConcurrentModificationException
                    unsafemap.put("testKey","testData");

                }
                System.out.println("---------------------------------");
                for(Map.Entry<String,String> e :unsafemap.entrySet()){
                    System.out.println(e);
                }
```

Modifying the map during iteration always results in an exception, if not done using the iterator e.g. iterator.remove(). So obviously adding a new value during iteration is throwing the exception as expected but why is it not thrown if the value of a particular key/value pair is modified?

Comment: Why should it? Have you modified the structure of the map?

Comment: So modifying only the keys of the map during iteration causes the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Entry` object already exists in your first case, so the value will just be modified using `e.value = value;` and return and no new Entry will be made. So, no exception here.

In second case, changes done to the value object really don't affect the map, so no exception there.

From `HashMap` source code:

```
public V put(K key, V value) {
     if (key == null)
         return putForNullKey(value);
     int hash = hash(key.hashCode());
     int i = indexFor(hash, table.length);
     for (Entry<K,V> e = table[i]; e != null; e = e.next) {
         Object k;
         if (e.hash == hash && ((k = e.key) == key || key.equals(k))) {
             V oldValue = e.value;
             e.value = value;
             e.recordAccess(this);
             return oldValue;
         }
     }

     modCount++;
     addEntry(hash, key, value, i);
     return null;
 }
```